# Linkedin correct app settings for android integration

Tags: android, linkedin-api, socialauth

I am using the socialauth library for integration with android app. The twitter and facebook updates are working correctly...however I am having problems with setting up the linkedin app.
I have determined that there is some problem with my settings of the linkedin app on the developers portal. The examples that come with social auth library works perfectly, the problem is only in my app settings that I've given on Linkedin developer network.

I couldn't find any guide or tutorial for the settings of app. I read the doc that is provided by Linkedin but since I am using a 3rd party library....its of no use because I can't get my head around the settings...

Can someone please help me?

P.S : I can login correctly to the app and authorize the problem is in posting updates.
I am getting a FileNotFoundException: http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares

Update: Can anybody give me the settings of Linkedin app that you use for android or iPhone integration??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the following issue reported at socialauth :

http://code.google.com/p/socialauth-android/issues/detail?id=3

The new sdk is going to release in this week which will solve your issue.

Comment: Hi the new version of socialauth sdk is released. It will help you to solve linkedin issue.